# Erro consulta webservice Nfce SP

Tags: java, web-service, nfe

Após a atualização para versão do java 8 estou com erro para consulta de status do webservice de Nfc-e de SP (https://homologacao.nfce.fazenda.sp.gov.br/ws/nfeconsulta2.asmx), sempre me retorna “**HTTPS hostname wrong:  should be homologacao.nfce.fazenda.sp.gov.br**”, porém como pode ver o hostname está correto, ao que parece e problema no certificado, alguém saberia me dizer o que está acontecendo?

Segue o trace da exceção:

```
Exception occurred in target VM: HTTPS hostname wrong:  should be <homologacao.nfce.fazenda.sp.gov.br> 
java.io.IOException: HTTPS hostname wrong:  should be <homologacao.nfce.fazenda.sp.gov.br>
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.checkURLSpoofing(HttpsClient.java:649)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:573)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1283)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1258)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionOldImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionOldImpl.java:220)
    at santri.repositorio.Biblioteca.enviarMensagemWebService(Biblioteca.java:1301)
    at santri.nfe.ws.ServicosWeb.getXmlRetorno(ServicosWeb.java:43)
    at santri.nfe.ws.ServicosWeb.statusServico(ServicosWeb.java:579)
    at santri.nfe.visual.VerificarStatusServidor.consultarStatus(VerificarStatusServidor.java:284)
    at santri.nfe.visual.VerificarStatusServidor.btStatusNFCeActionPerformed(VerificarStatusServidor.java:234)
    at santri.nfe.visual.VerificarStatusServidor.access$200(VerificarStatusServidor.java:14)
    at santri.nfe.visual.VerificarStatusServidor$3.actionPerformed(VerificarStatusServidor.java:101)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at org.pushingpixels.substance.internal.utils.RolloverButtonListener.mouseReleased(RolloverButtonListener.java:124)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```